# How to implement simultaneous interaction in Sugarscape simulation?

Tags: simulation, simultaneous

[Youtube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAXWoRcT4NM)

So in this simulation, agents (represented by dots) choose one direction to move according to surrounding circumstances. Theoretically all agents make the decision and move simultaneously, but what if two dots decided to move to the same position and collide with each other? How in practice does the program solve this?

My guess is it actually executes the calculation one by one in order but this somehow violates the presumed requirement of simultaneous interaction. Because any dot's calculated move advanced in time might change the other one's surroundings of status quo, thus alters the intended move of the latter. On the other hand this seems to be the only way to avoid collision problems.

Any help thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Sugarscape is a class of models with many implementations, some open source, some proprietary.  The answer to your question would depend on the specifics of the implementation.

Comment: I think my question is implementation tool irrelevant, and it has nothing to do with solutions being open source or proprietary.

Comment: I know at least three different straightforward implementation strategies used for time-stepped state updates: 1) iterator-based traversal of the agent set; 2) randomized traversal; and 3) two-stage traversal with updates pre-calculated on the first pass and applied on the second pass. If you use a proprietary implementation which doesn't document their choice, there's no way to tell which is being applied. With open source, you can see how they implemented it.  And it matters -- in practice these can give very different results for nominally identical implementations of a simulation model.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening! But I assume the three strategies you mentioned could still be categorized into two methods as I described? The iterator method avoids collision but it's essentially equivalent to the scenario that agents move in sequence rather than simultaneously at discrete time; the two-stage method can't rule out collision, or can it? More explanation is highly appreciated!

Comment: Just found this related question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5906/collision-resolution